# Array with spot light as child possible?

Tags: modifiers

Beginner question:

I have an object with a light as child.

I want to use the array modifier with the object and hoped, the lamp would be "arrayed" too but it isn't.

What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: not really answer, but yeah, it is a workaround

Comment: It's not possible to use modifiers on lamp objects so no, but you can array a single vertex or a face and use that as an instancer like in the linked q&a